# ASP.NET Core 2.2 WebApi Status Code 415 on authentication error

Tags: asp.net, authentication, .net-core, jwt, .net-core-2.2

I have an interesting error in my ASP.NET Core 2.2 WebApi project.

I implemented JWT authentication which works well:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            var signigKey = Convert.FromBase64String(AuthSettings.IssuerSigningKey);

            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateAudience = false, // Not required as no third-party is involved
                ValidateIssuer = false, // Not required as no third-party is involved
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(signigKey)
            };
        });
    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseAuthentication();
    ...
}
```

Now when I use an invalid bearer token, the api returns the status code 415 instead of 401. But the headers are as expected (invalid signature...).

I figured out the problem is the `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` middleware. The middleware works fine when I force a 404 error.

When i remove the middelware the status code in my not-authenticated request is 401.

Does anyone have an idea?

Greetings,
Philip

Comment: I guess UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute is above UseAuthentication in the Configure method?

Comment: Yes, this is true. Should it work, if UseAuthentication is above?

Comment: No, I think the authentication should below the StatusCode pages. Haven't seen any code so far where the StatusCode pages haven't been quite on the top.

Comment: Status code 415 indicates you may are trying to do send a request as content-type "text/plain" to something that excepts "application/json". And this (routing middleware?, action invoker?) seems to detect and return the error before the authentication middleware checks for the valid token. What else is in your Configure method (especially before the authentication)? After all I would bet it is a pipeline configuration (middleware order) issue